# Can you Create Your Own Default T where T is your own class

Tags: .net, default, keyword

lets say I have the following

```
public class A 
{
   private string _someField;
   public string SomeField { get { return _someField; } }
}
```

For some reason I am checking the default of this class and I would like to set the default for a class, just like a default of type int is  0, I would like in the above class for my default of Somefield to be "hello";

```
int i = default(int); // i is 0
A myClass = default(A);
string s = myClass.SomeField; // s is hello
```

This is more just for my own theoretical satisfaction rather than practical application.  Just wondering.

Comment: I think a few of you dont know what the default keyword is
test your code that you wrote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of overloading default(T).

To me, it really sounds like you're asking for non-nullable reference types which don't yet exist in .NET.  Have a look here for an implementation: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/06/non-nullable-reference-types.aspx

Comment: That is an interesting way around it Stefan, given that a struct is non nullable.

Answer (score 5):

No.  The default for classes (reference types) is `null` and cannot be overloaded.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot change what default(T) is for a T.  It is always null for reference types, and the 'empty' value for value types (ie. for a struct, all members are at their default, uninitalized values).

Answer (score 0):

In case of classes (reference types) the default keyword doesn't do anything for the members of the class, it just sets the whole reference to null

Answer (score 0):

While default() will always return null, you could use where to specify that the class must contain a parameterless constructor, so you can call new on it.

```
void SomeMethod<T>(T something) where T : new()
    {
        T newObject = new T();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job:

```
public class A 
{
   private string _someField = "hello";
   public string SomeField { get { return _someField; } }
}
```

Now when you create an instance of that class, the initial value of someField will be hello.

[Edit: 
This doesn't do quite what you want. Like others have noted in the comments, default(T) where T is a class will always result in null.

Instead you would create the class normally instead of using the 'default' keyword.

```
A myClass = new A();
string defaultValue = myClass.SomeField // This will be set to "hello" by default.
```

]

Comment: default(T) is always null, that's the value after calling the default constructor.

Comment: This will cause a null reference exception when myClass is dereferenced.

Comment: -1 If it were a struct perhaps but a default of T where T : class is always null.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, fair point, this wouldn't quite work with your existing code. You would just create the class normally - not using the keyword 'default' and the value of someField would always be set to "hello" when the class is first created.

Comment: @Simon P Stevens: While your statement is true it really has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Simon P Stevens: In order for that to work you would have to constrain the generic type parameter with "new()" so that you could invoke the type's default constructor.

Comment: I've edited to define the usage more clearly. The way I read the question is that the OP wanted a way of having a default value for his class members, yes it isn't done in the way he originally wanted, but this is an appropriate alternative.

Comment: @Andrew: woah, have I really misunderstood the question, where does it mention generics? He just uses the letter 'T' I don't think he wants a generic. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Simon: Oops!  No I misread it - you are correct, the OP doesn't seem to mention generics anywhere!

Comment: @Simon: I have removed my downvote as you have corrected the error and what your question now says is correct.

Comment: @Andrew: Appreciate it, but I think as it turns out I was in the wrong - Brandon was clearly asking about the "semantics of default" as he mentions somewhere else. I'll leave this here in case its useful to someone else.